# Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction - Limit on parameters?

Tags: apex, visualforce

```
Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction('{!$RemoteAction.Classname.MethodName}', Parameter1,Parameter2,Parameter3,function(result, event) {
```

I am calling methods using Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction. Is there any limit on the number of parameters that can be passed , or any number of parameters is okay?

Comment: Apex had (and probably still has) a limit of 32 on the number of parameters a method can have. I assume the remoting does not impose a lower limit.